# jQuery each and find call not working on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html-parsing

I'm trying to search an html document for dl's and return/store their 'id' attribute. However when I include a chained 'each' function, nothing is found, and when i do a single 'find' function call, the id attribute is returned as undefined, even though it isnt. This is what the html im searching through looks like:

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>blah Resources</title>
  <link href="blah" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
<span>Resources</span>    
<dl id="/data/file.docx">
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>blah</dd>
  <dt>URL</dt>
  <dd>blah</dd>
  <dt>Last-Modified</dt>

</dl>
<dl id="/data/app.js">
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>app.js</dd>
  <dt>URL</dt>
  <dd>blah</dd>
</dl>
<dl id="/data/date.txt">
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>blah</dd>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what my code looks like (the ajax call is fine, it is successful):

```
    function processHTML(html){

        alert("processHTML was called");

        $(html).find('dl').each(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(url);

        });
    };
```

In the above code, nothing gets alerted. And in the below code, what is alerted simply comes up as 'undefined'.

```
    function processHTML(html){

        alert("processHTML was called");

        var url = $(html).find('dl').attr('id');
        alert(url);
    };
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit:
For comparison, the following code works perfectly fine and resides in a different js file I have, im struggling to see the difference between this working example and my non working one above.

given this html doc:

```
<html><head>
<title>blah</title>
<LINK href="resources.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head><body>
<span>Resources</span>    <dl id="tool">
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>Tool1</dd>
  <dt>URL</dt>
  <dt>Created</dt>
  <dd>date</dd>
</dl>
<dl id="tool">
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>Tool2</dd>
  <dt>URL</dt>
  <dt>Created</dt>
  <dd>date</dd>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

this code works perfectly fine:

```
function processHTML(html){
var name = "";
var url;

$(html).find('dt').each(function(){
    var property = $(this).text();
    if(property == "Name"){
        var temp = $(this).next().text();
        name = "";
    }
    alert(name);
}
};
```

alerts:

Tool1

Tool2

Comment: have you checked you get response in html variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `$()` to parse HTML, everything but the contents of `body` are stripped out (more details [in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)), so `$("<html><body><dl></dl></body></html>")` is effectively the same as `$("<dl></dl>")` (and in fact, `console.log($("<body><dl></dl></body>")[0].tagName`) will log `DL`).

So when you parse your HTML, you end up with a jQuery object with four top-level elements: A `span` and three `dl`s.

[`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) looks for *descendants* of the elements at the top level of the jQuery object, but since the `dl`s *are* top level elements, `find` didn't find anything.

**If** the `dl`s will always be immediate children of `body` in that HTML snippet, you can just use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) instead of `find`:

```
$(html).filter('dl').each(...)
```

**but** if the `dl`s may be inside something else, or if you just want to allow for them to be at some stage, you might combine `find` with [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf):

```
$(html).find('dl').andSelf('dl').each(...)
```

I'd probably go with the latter.

---

Side note: `$(this).attr("id")` is a *really* roundabout way to get `this.id`.

---

Live example of `$(html).filter('dl')`:

```js
var html =
  '<html><head>' +
  '<title>blah</title>' +
  '<LINK href="resources.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>' +
  '</head><body>' +
  '<span>Resources</span>    <dl id="tool">' +
  '  <dt>Name</dt>' +
  '  <dd>Tool1</dd>' +
  '  <dt>URL</dt>' +
  '  <dt>Created</dt>' +
  '  <dd>date</dd>' +
  '</dl>' +
  '<dl id="tool">' +
  '  <dt>Name</dt>' +
  '  <dd>Tool2</dd>' +
  '  <dt>URL</dt>' +
  '  <dt>Created</dt>' +
  '  <dd>date</dd>' +
  '</dl>' +
  '</body>' +
  '</html>';
$(html).filter('dl').each(function() {
  snippet.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Live example of `$(html).find('dl').andSelf('dl')`:

```js
var html =
  '<html><head>' +
  '<title>blah</title>' +
  '<LINK href="resources.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>' +
  '</head><body>' +
  '<span>Resources</span>    <dl id="tool">' +
  '  <dt>Name</dt>' +
  '  <dd>Tool1</dd>' +
  '  <dt>URL</dt>' +
  '  <dt>Created</dt>' +
  '  <dd>date</dd>' +
  '</dl>' +
  '<dl id="tool">' +
  '  <dt>Name</dt>' +
  '  <dd>Tool2</dd>' +
  '  <dt>URL</dt>' +
  '  <dt>Created</dt>' +
  '  <dd>date</dd>' +
  '</dl>' +
  '</body>' +
  '</html>';
$(html).find('dl').andSelf('dl').each(function() {
  snippet.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/tax1f3pe/). use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of find.

**[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**  Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

**[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
  $(html).filter('dl').each(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(url);
  });
```

Comment: filter indeed works perfectly, thanks ! still trying to wrap my head around why find didnt work, i've updated my op to include an example that does work for me, and it doesnt skip the found element.

Comment: @dalva here in your what you mean by different js file ??